# Weird FileNotFound error in andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I wanted to load some textureRegion like (just example)

```
weapons=BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(a,this,"gfx/optionItems1/GO_BUTTOM.png",388,0);
```

but it gave me the error, so i checked to see if it was there, and it was. So i tried to see if it was a coding error so i replaced it with

```
weapons=BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(a,this,"gfx/optionItems1/weapons_buttom.png",388,0);
```

and it worked perfectly, now i see that there is a whole set of png with this problem. I dont understand why, they are in the same place (and with same size) as the counterparts that work.

Comment: I'm not sure but it may be that file names have to be lowercase.

Comment: Playing with it i found you were right. The first letter has to be lowercase

Comment: Well I thought that all letter have to be lowercase but seams that we both learn :)